# Python subprocess.Popen - How to capture childs backtrace upon abort

Tags: python, subprocess, stack-trace, backtrace

I want to run a process in a loop and if the process returns 0, I must rerun it. If it aborts, I have to capture its stack trace (backtrace). I'm using `subprocess.Popen()` and `.communicate()` to run the process. Now `.returncode` is 134, i.e. child has received SIGABRT, is there any way I can capture the backtrace (stack trace) of child?
Since this is a testing tool, I have to capture all the necessary information before I forward it to dev team.

Comment: show your code :P

Comment: Chances are the traceback is printed to stderr... so you just have to read your child process's stderr.

Comment: Unfortunately code is copyrighted. When run manually backtrace is not printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4039/print-stack-trace-of-a-core-file-without-needing-to-enter-gdb-interactively) site and last comment of @Marco, I can fetch the backtrace from core

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to redirect stdout and stderr of your subprocess.Popen() to a file and later on check that.

Doing like that it should be possible to check the backtrace later the "process Termination".

Good logging mechanism will give you that :-) Hope this help enough.

Comment: When run manually backtrace is not printed. The below error is printed when it aborts: `Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff5d06b55 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6`. What I wanted is backtrace right from `main()` till this.

Comment: To see the backtrace are you using some special commands like gdb or do you allow creation of core files? Unfortunately I am not an expert of this, but point is...1) if the subprocess is not returning 0 then you can check created core file. 2) as said before you can redirect stderr and stdout to a file (but I doubt than the backtrace will be logged like that). 3) Check the journal on the linux system maybe to get more insight.

Comment: @Macro yeah, while running manually, I'm using gdb. I'm aware of core, but dev team prefers stack trace. backtrace is not logged in stdout and stderr.

Comment: @user2763554 as expected backtrace are not logged too normal stdout and err. Maybe I have one different solution for you that is quite easy to implement and can be used live. What you can do is to start a two threads program --> first thread is running your proprietary testing tool, second thread is indeed checking the tool using the gdb as you should do manually. Could it be possible for you to implement like that? Then it should work.

Comment: Last thing...if core files are generated you can parse them offline --> getting the trace from the core and report to Dev Team. Hope one of the way can be implemented by you...unfortunately I am not the main expert on this field!! Have a nice day!!